# How to remove a field and set default value for a ModelForm in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a ModelForm in my forms.py as follows:

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Choice
    fields = ['choice_text', 'is_choice_correct']
    labels = {
        'choice_text': "",
        'is_choice_correct': ""
    }
    widgets = {
        "choice_text": forms.Textarea(),
        "is_choice_correct": "",
    }
```

Based on some conditions, I would like the `is_correct_field`, a boolean field to not display in the form and set default value for the field (because it is required) so that when I write `form.save()` in my views, there occurs no error.

However, I don't want to hide the form field. To make it more clear, here's what I want to say. I submit the form with only `choice_text` in my form. The form does not contain the field `is_choice_correct`, either hidden or displayed. When I save the form with form.save(), I want the `is_choice_correct` to be True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not declare the default value for `is_choice_correct`on the model itself?

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    is_choice_correct = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then exclude the field from the form as Exprator shows. 
If you want to include the field on the form only under some conditions, you can edit the form's `.fields` during `__init__`.

```
class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs) # important, call super() first or the form has no .fields attribute
        if my_condition:
            self.fields['is_choice_correct'] = Choice._meta.get_field('is_choice_correct').formfield()
```